# CSS: Is it possible to change this Accordion so that I can close the slides?

Tags: css

I have the following CSS for an accordion, which works fine. However once a slide has been opened, it's not possible to close it again without refreshing the page entirely. Is it possible/simple to add something so that a user can close the slides again when they click on one?

There's some js that is referenced in the HTML for this accordion, but I'm not sure if it actually gets used, or if the changes would need to be in there.

I'm considering just finding a new accordion CSS that does what I need, would that be faster? If so could someone point me in the right direction please?

Apologies, still new with how CSS works.

```
/**
 *  CSS3 Only Horizontal and Vertical Accordion
 *  Author: Paul Underwood for Hongkiat.com
 *  Website: www.paulund.co.uk
 *  Date: 27/11/11
 *  Version: 1.0
 */


article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, nav, section { display: block; }
audio, canvas, video { display: inline-block; *display: inline; *zoom: 1; }
audio:not([controls]) { display: none; }
[hidden] { display: none; }
html { font-size: 100%; overflow-y: scroll; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%; }
body { margin: 0; font-size: 13px; line-height: 1.231; }
body, button, input, select, textarea { font-family: sans-serif; color: #222; }

/*Define Accordion box*/
.accordion { width:700px; overflow:hidden; margin:10px auto; color:#474747; background:#414141; padding:10px; }

/*General Accordion****************************************************************************/
/*Set style of open slide*/
.accordion section:target { background:#FFF; padding:10px;}
.accordion section:target:hover { background:#FFF; }
.accordion section:target h2 {width:100%;}
.accordion section:target h2 a{ color:#333; padding:0;}
.accordion section:target p {display:block;}
.accordion section h2 a{padding:8px 10px;display:block; font-size:16px; font-weight:normal;color:#eee; text-decoration:none; }

/*set style of closed slide*/
.accordion section{ float:left; overflow:hidden; color:#139fec; cursor:pointer; background: #139fec; margin:3px; }
.accordion section:hover {background:#7fc5ec;}
.accordion section p { display:none; }
.accordion section:after{position:relative;font-size:24px;color:#000;font-weight:bold;}
.accordion section:nth-child(1):after{content:'1';}
.accordion section:nth-child(2):after{content:'2';}
.accordion section:nth-child(3):after{content:'3';}
.accordion section:nth-child(4):after{content:'4';}
.accordion section:nth-child(5):after{content:'5';}
/*End General Accordion****************************************************************************/

/*Horizontal Accordion *********************************************************************/
.horizontal section{ width:5%; height:250px; 
    -moz-transition:width 0.2s ease-out; 
    -webkit-transition:width 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition:width 0.2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition:width 0.2s ease-out;
    transition:width 0.2s ease-out;
}

/*Position the number of the slide*/
.horizontal section:after{top:140px;left:15px;}

/*Header of closed slide*/
.horizontal section h2 { 
    -webkit-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    width:240px; position:relative; left:-100px; top:85px;
} 

/*On mouse over open slide*/
.horizontal :target{ width:73%;height:230px; }
.horizontal :target h2{ top:0px;left:0;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg); 
}
/*End Horizontal Accordion *********************************************************************/

/*Vertical Accordion *************************************************************************/
.vertical section{ width:100%; height:40px;
    -webkit-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
    -moz-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
    -o-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
    -ms-transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
    transition:height 0.2s ease-out;
}
/*Set height of the slide*/
.vertical :target{ height:250px; width:97%; }

.vertical section h2 { position:relative; left:0; top:-15px; }

/*Set position of the number on the slide*/
.vertical section:after{ top:-60px;left:810px;}
.vertical section:target:after{ left:-9999px;}

.accordion img{
    display:inline-block;
    width:211px;
    height:146px;
    border:1px solid white;
    vertical-align:top;
    margin-right:10px;
}

.accordion div{
    display:inline-block;
    width:311px;
}
```

Comment: What you want certainly is possible.  Can you post the javascript you mentioned above, and perhaps even make a working JSFiddle for us?  jsfiddle.net

Comment: Hi there. Whether or not the js is actually relevant to the accordion I can't tell. I actually removed the JS and it seemed to work exactly the same as before. Anyway, here's the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Fzw2R/

Comment: thanks for adding the javascript.  You are correct, the javascript you posted is the HTML5 shiv, it helps standardize browsers that don't fully support HTML5.  You shouldn't remove it from your site unless you replace what it does with another method, but that's something for you to look into later on.  I'll review your above code and see if I can devise a way to modify it without having to resort to javascript, since what you have now is pure CSS.

Comment: Thought I should mention, that this accordion was designed to work without js. I checked the site again: http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css-content-accordion/ to be sure. Which is why the link to JS kinda confused me. - Thanks, you posted above just as I did :)

Comment: There's really not enough information here for us to figure out what's going on.  You will get better answers if you provide a small self-contained example, which contains just enough code to demonstrate the problem, without anything extra. Post this code into the question, AND in a JSFiddle (jsfiddle.net). Doing this can be a lot of work, but it's a critical part of the process of troubleshooting your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a collapse code for it to close:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#xxx" ).xxx({  // Place your Ids/Classes relevant to the accordion  //
        collapsible: true
    });
});
```